# Inner Query In Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Trying to write a stored procedure. I have a cursor in the stored procedure which produces the following output.

```
 ID1 | Range | Action | Version | Name
--------------------------------------
  1  | 1-3,  |        |         |
     | 5-7   |   D    |   V0    |  U1
  2  | 10-11 |   A    |   V0    |  U2
  3  | 15-18 |   A    |   V1    |  U3
```

Where range is a `ID` of another table `UPCListDetails`.

```
 ID | UPCName
--------------
 1  | Test
 2  | Test1
 3  | Test2
 10 | Test10
...
```

Now I need to query `UPCListDetails` table with the range column and produce a output

```
 ID1 | ID | UPCName | Action | Version | Name
----------------------------------------------
 1   | 1  | Test    | D      | V0      | U1
 1   | 2  | Test1   | D      | V0      | U1
 1   | 3  | Test2   | D      | V0      | U1
 2   | 10 | Test10  | A      | V1      | U2
```

Basically I need to query the UPCListDetails table with range (low and high value from range column) and store it in some variable and then inject the value in to the result again. I was reading about PLSQL collections but i was not able to understand it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Is the output from the cursor for id1 = 1 on two rows, or is the data in the range column "1-3, 5-7"?

Comment: Thanks Boneist for reply. It is a single row . Range column value is "1-3, 5-7" . It can also be without "-" like "10-11" (depicted in second row in above example)

Answer (score 0):

It would be preferable to maintain the ranges using 2 columns and a row per range:

```
ID1  Range_From  Range_To  Action Version Name
1    1           3         D      V0      U1
2    5           7         D      V0      U1
3    10          11        A      V0      U2
4    15          18        A      V1      U3
```

Then you simply need a query like

```
select u.ID, u.UPCName, r.Action r.Version r.Name
from   UPCListDetails u
       join range_table r
       on u.ID between r.range_from and r.range_to;
```

That way you avoid having to parse ranges, and lists of ranges.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get the cursor in your procedure changed so that it outputs data in the format that @TonyAndrews' solution suggests, then I would recommend that you go with that.

However, if you're stuck with that cursor output, then you'll need to do the work to convert it into that format:

```
with      output as (select 1 id1, '1-3, 5-7' range, 'D' action, 'V0' version, 'U1' name from dual union all
                     select 2 id1, '10-11' range, 'A' action, 'V0' version, 'U2' name from dual union all
                     select 3 id1, '15-18' range, 'A' action, 'V1' version, 'U3' name from dual),
         main_op as (select id1,
                            regexp_substr(regexp_substr(replace(range, ' '), '[^,]+', 1, level), '[^-]+', 1, 1) range_from,
                            regexp_substr(regexp_substr(replace(range, ' '), '[^,]+', 1, level), '[^-]+', 1, 2) range_to,
                            action,
                            version,
                            name
                     from   output
                     connect by prior id1 = id1
                                and level <= regexp_count(range, ',') + 1
                                and prior dbms_random.value is not null),
  upclistdetails as (select 1 id, 'Test' upcname from dual union all
                     select 2 id, 'Test1' upcname from dual union all
                     select 3 id, 'Test2' upcname from dual union all
                     select 10 id, 'Test10' upcname from dual)
select mo.id1,
       uld.id,
       uld.upcname,
       mo.action,
       mo.version,
       mo.name
from   upclistdetails uld
       inner join main_op mo on uld.id between mo.range_from and mo.range_to;

       ID1         ID UPCNAME ACTION VERSION NAME
---------- ---------- ------- ------ ------- ----
         1          1 Test    D      V0      U1  
         1          2 Test1   D      V0      U1  
         1          3 Test2   D      V0      U1  
         2         10 Test10  A      V0      U2
```

What the main_op subquery does is to first of all produce as many rows for each id1 as there are range chunks (eg. for id1 = 1, there are 2 range chunks), outputting each chunk on its own row.

Then we take the element before the hyphen and use that as the "range_from" column, and similarly we take the element after the hyphen for the "range_to".

Once you have the output looking like that, it's just a matter of joining it to the upclistdetails table to get your final results.